# How does PHP's `mail` work?

Tags: email, php

PHP's `mail` function seems to deliver mail on a clean system, with no apparent configuration done by the administrator or webmaster (no SMTP configuration in `php.ini`, etc.). How does the `mail` function deliver mail to a remote server?

Comment: Why should that configuration been done? Unless you mean delivering mail to the webmaster, it doesn't make sense for the webmaster to configure things.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question - there is nothing wrong with the mail() function in PHP - it's not unreliable. The problem is contents and distribution of your mails. A better question would be 'how can I avoid my mails ending in the spam folder?'.

Comment: he said 'reliable' but this is really not a question for...here

Comment: @Alex of course it is. I was asking how it works, not how to avoid the spam folder.

Comment: I'd like to know why this is getting downvoted...? This is a legitimate question, asking how a function of a scripting language works.

Comment: Often PHP is a frontend for system commands / c commands with a strong reliance on linux. So looking for a manpage and a same named command can often help, too. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mail

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On *nix it invokes the `sendmail` binary, which then uses the mail configuration to route the email. On Windows, it sends to a SMTP server. In both cases the sysadmin sets up the mail system.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question I asked. I wasn't sure if PHP was contacting the remote server itself and handling the SMTP, or if it handed off that task to the MTA on the local server. Also, do you know why this question is being downvoted? I think a lot of people simply misunderstood it. It seems to fit into the scope of the site (as defined by [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)) well.

Comment: @Tom: People have fixated on the wording rather than the question.

Comment: I've modified the question to help rectify the problem. I don't understand what is "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical" about it. I tried asking in the PHP chatroom but no moderators were in there or none of them replied. Is there a better place to learn about the site?

Comment: could you be clearer about "the mail configuration" that sendmail uses ?

Comment: @vaab: No. It completely depends on your MTA.

Comment: I am now helping someone with a website hosted on 1and1. I scanned and found no mail configuration settings in any of the website files. Does it mean that the MTA is configured by 1and1 and made available for all PHP apps to use? This is quite unusual as web sites done in other languages require the customer to find his own SMTP forwarder (never mind that I can just go and create an email address in my domain hosted in 1and1 and then use that credential to use 1and1's SMTP server, but at least spam can be easier traced) .

Answer (score 13):

You can detect how it works as below.

## First method

```
$ ltrace php -r "mail('tester@127.0.0.1', 'Test', 'Hello world');" 2>&1 | grep sendmail
memcpy(0x095ea168, "sendmail_from", 14)          = 0x095ea168
memcpy(0x095ea1e0, "sendmail_path", 14)          = 0x095ea1e0
popen("/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i ", "w")          = 0x0977c7c0
```

From the results of the above command can be seen that the `popen()` function opens the process of `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`.

```
$ ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail
... /usr/sbin/sendmail -> exim4
```

So `sendmail` is the symbolic link to `exim4` and hence `sendmail -t -i` invokes `exim4 -t -i`.

And in the manual page of `exim4` you can read about these options `-t -i`:

```
$ man exim4 | grep ' -t -i'
-ti       This option is exactly equivalent to -t -i. It is provided for compatibility with Sendmail.
```

## Second method

Install [snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy) and run:

```
# grep snoopy /var/log/auth.log | tail
... php -r mail('tester@127.0.0.1', 'Test', 'Hello world');
... /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
... /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YxxYn-0006a7-Nw
... /usr/sbin/exim4 -t -oem -oi -f <> -E1YxxYn-0006a7-Nw
... /usr/sbin/exim4 -Mc 1YxxYn-0006aB-Oj
```

The results of the above command show the sequence of the commands which were performed.

Answer (score 9):

mail() uses sendmail, that uses DNS to find MX record of target domain and delivers there directly. thats it.

and since destination server probably does not know your ip address, especially if it is NATed it may be marked as spam.

you can modify your config to use different (legit ad known) smtp server to act as intermediary.

Answer (score 5):

It's really not that reliable, actually, unless the underlying `sendmail` or something is properly configured.

Amazon SES has better servers than whatever server you're using and gets mail there more times than with `mail()`.

The real reason you shouldn't use `mail()` is because your server's IP address is probably completely unknown to mail services such as GMail, Yahoo, etc, and there is a higher chance it will get marked as spam. Why does it get marked as spam? Because `mail()` is very easy and simple to exploit for spam purposes.

Comment: This isn't really answering the question, which was how does it work. I use SES for other things. This was simply wanting to know how it works on a clean install with no configuration, not why it gets marked as spam or what I should use instead. Thanks for the answer, though.