# Sending Mails from localhost in PHP

Tags: php, email

today I found out, that I can send mails using mail() in PHP from my mac book using XAMPP. It works, they are blocked on most providers, e.g. gmail because of the dynamic IP, but some providers receive it!

But HOW does it works even without having a mail-server installed? I always thought, that's necessary for sending mails...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811711/how-does-phps-mail-work

Comment: Not at all. What is typically referred to as a "mail server" is required to _receive_ emails and to _access received emails_. But not to send them. What happens in your case simply is that your function call results in an smtp request to some smtp server (the receiving side). Just like a http request to some web server, where the client obviously does _not_ require an own http server to make a request.

Comment: thank you arkascha, now I've got it :)

Answer (score 0):

How it works is by using SMTP:

http://cr.yp.to/smtp.html

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt

PHP configuration details:

http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php