# The difference between CodeIngiter Email Protocol sendmail,mail and SMTP?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I´m currently doing a presentation on CodeIngiter Email library vs External. I dont understand the difference between the several email configuration protocols except SMTP. There is an avaible question but seems confusing and I appreciate a simpler aproach pointing the clear differences.

Also I can´t find in CodeIgniter manual anything about it, simply states that exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is a confusion here.

[SMTP](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), *Simple Mail Transfer Protocol*, is really the underlying protocol used for email. Every existing solutions, libraries or services are based on this.

CodeIgniter gives us a useful [library class *Mail*](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html), which is basically an object-oriented wrapper aiming to simplify the sending of mail from your PHP application. For instance, it allows you to do this:

```php
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();
```

This is fairly straightforward and nice to read.

Now, this class can be configured in a lot of different way. And I agree that the documentation does a poor job explaining it. And I guess the thing that may have confused you is this sentence:
`Multiple Protocols: Mail, Sendmail, and SMTP`, which in the configuration table is given as:

**protocol**: `mail`, `sendmail`, or `smtp` *The mail sending protocol.*

It would be used like this:

```php
$config = ['protocol' => 'sendmail'];
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

What does these value means?

---

### mail

The default value is `mail`.

It means that the CodeIgniter library will use the internal [`mail()` PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to try to send the mail.

How does it works? How does PHP know how to send the mail?

> On Unix/Linux it invokes the `sendmail` binary, which then uses the mail
>   configuration to route the email. On Windows, it sends to a SMTP
>   server. In both cases the sysadmin sets up the mail system.

[Thanks to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11811740/8861729)

In any case, the `sendmail` binary will then use a SMTP server to send the mail, as configured by the admin.

### sendmail

The second possible value is `sendmail`.

Using `sendmail` value for the configuration means that the CodeIgniter library will use directly the `sendmail` binary without using the PHP `mail()` function.

The path to the binary can be configured through the option `mailpath` (which is `/usr/sbin/sendmail` by default).

This means that this can only be used on Linux/Unix platform, as Windows doesn't have any `sendmail` binary.

Now why would you want to use the `sendmail` binary directly since the PHP internal `mail()` function already uses it (and is compatible with Windows)?

Well, for one the `mail()` internal function could be disabled in your PHP environment by your hosting provider. Or you may want to call a special `sendmail` binary different than the one used by the PHP internal function.

In any case, the `sendmail` binary will then use a SMTP server to send the mail, as configured by the admin.

### SMTP

The last possible value is `smtp`.

Using `smtp` value for the configuration means that the CodeIgniter library will connect directly to a SMTP server in order to send the mail.

The way the connection is performed can be configured with the relevant `smtp_*` options, which are `smtp_host`, `smtp_user`, `smtp_pass`, `smtp_port` and so on...

This option is really useful when you are not the admin of the server (e.g. in a shared hosting environment) and thus can't configure the SMTP provider for the server.

It is also better to choose this rather than the other alternative, because your application will no longer depends on the server proper configuration.

---

### Summary

The main issue here is that the class and the documentation wrongly use the term `protocol`.

SMTP is the protocol for email.

The option `mail`, `sendmail` and `smtp` are more like *endpoints*, or *sending methods*, i.e. what the library should use in order to send the mail.

I hope this clarifies the documentation a little bit.