# Laravel send mail with default credentials

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to send a mail via laravel.
Without Laravel it's no proplem for me using

`$headers = "From: ".FROM_MAIL;
mail(TO_MAIL, "Subject", "Text", $headers);`

In Laravels .env file I have to set some credentials but do I really need to do this? Because it seems to work with default credentials set anywhere in the server.

So my question is: How do I configure the .env file correctly?

If I set nothing:

`MAIL_DRIVER=
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mail@hoster.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
MAIL_FROM_NAME="From Name"`

I get the following error:
`Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), 0 passed in /mnt/web409/e0/11/59802411/htdocs/test/crm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php on line 96 and exactly 1 expected`

FYI: I am using a server of Strato!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to see what is the host address it should be something like this. smtp.strato.de and username@desirename.de and the rest of the configuration. and the reason you can send email from your local with mail function is becaus, you can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811711/how-does-phps-mail-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who has the same problem as me:

In the config/mail.php file 'sendmail' => `'/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',` must be replaced by `'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i',`.

Also, the configuration must look like the one in my comment under the reply from Danny Ebbers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel you should actually not using mail() directly as this is a native php function

read: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail

That should explain you how, you supposed to work with emails in laravel.

If you have no idea, how this email works, that probably is the case, you probably are looking to use the driver 'sendmail' which is similar to the native mail() function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

If this is a good choice, depends on your goals, requirements and server setup

Comment: If I try to configure it like that:
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.strato.de
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mail@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="From Name"
I get:
"Expected response code 220 but got an empty response"

Am I able to see more details here?