Source Email security with MailMessage and Mail functions (C# and PHP) curiosity question
The work I have been doing for a summer internship has led to me use a couple mail functions, ex: MailMessage and Mail (C# and PHP respectively). A couple sources online have mentioned that C# needs credential verification to send from an email address. In the PHP files where I used the mail function, I never had to supply credentials. I was wondering if there is normally a mail verification service that emails have to go through before getting sent out on the companies network? There must be security blocking people from using mail functions with any email they want, but what is the typical way of doing this?
This is just out of curiosity from seeing discussions in other threads. No specific help on a problem I am facing. Nothing on the PHP and SMTP websites was standing out as helpful so I thought I would ask here. Thanks!

In PHP, the credentials are likely in your php.ini file.

Depending on what you are talking about, there's SPF which is a specific DNS record that tells receiving MTAs which IPs are allowed to send email for a given domain. While looking into that, it is worth looking into DKIM and DMARC, too, probably. Additionally, your specific PHP install might be set to route through an MTA that has this setup already.

Agreed, it depends on the protocol and the mail routing setup, not on the programming language you're using to generate the email. But yes, authentication to the mailserver may prevent people from sending from an account they don't own, and also SPF/DKIM/DMARC all play a part in allowing a receiving mailserver to verify that the email came from who it says it did, and that it hasn't been tampered with.

@ADyson, Ahh ok cool thank you. That helps a lot. Hopefully then since this is a pre-set up server I am working with they will already have these emails authenticated. That will help with not having to give credentials to the C# file using the mail function

No problem. Note that in PHP's case, mail() simply invokes the sendmail binary on the system (or on Windows, sends via an SMTP server) - but the connection and any authentication settings are not stored in the PHP program, they are in the sendmail or PHP configuration files, which is why it appears you can send an email without any credentials from your program. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811711/how-does-phps-mail-work. In your C# program you can try to emulate that by storing the SMTP settings somewhere, or you can simply put them in the app itself.

@nellyjelly56, since you are interning and learning, I think it is also helpful to be aware of this answer if you have to troubleshoot anything. Also, understanding the difference between sending email and users actually receiving it, especially in their inbox. Sending is relatively easy. But that ease is why spam became a thing and why we have these other things.

@ADyson, That link was incredibly helpful. Thank you!
